# When I try to use css modules in a vue app nothing happens and no class is generated

Tags: css, vue.js, webpack, css-modules, css-loader

I have the following setup in webpack for css modules:

```
modules: {
        mode: "local",
        auto: true,
        exportGlobals: true,
        localIdentName: "[path][name]__[local]--[hash:base64:5]",
        localIdentContext: path.resolve(__dirname, "src")
      }
```

The problem is that when I try to use modules in vue components nothing happens. If I set :class="$style.red", no class will appear there. I tried with vue components and module.css files but nothing works. What am I missing?

I would like to have scss modules, but for now it will be great if a simple css module will work.